# android: picture successfully loaded from gallery but dissapears after application restart

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gallery

so if the title sounds confusig, this is what actually happens. In the Activity I have a ImageView and it has a defalut picture. This defalut picture should be shown as long as the user picks another picture from gallery. When he does that, the picture which he picked should be shown as long as he doesn't delete it or picks another one. If he deletes it, the default picture should be shown again until he picks new picture from the gallery.
I have successfuly loaded the picture from the gallery but it stays in the imageview only until the applications restarts. After which the default picture will be shown again. Is there any way to fix this?

This is my code

```
package com.pumperlgsund.activities;

imports...

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
OnHeadlineSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {

private static int LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
private String selectedImagePath;

private ImageView imgUser;

private TextView txtName;
private TextView txtScore;
private TextView txtValue;

private UserDataController controller;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/ComicNeueSansID.ttf");

    controller = new UserDataController(this);

    imgUser = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgUser);
    imgUser.setOnClickListener(this);

    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
    txtName.setTypeface(tf);
    txtName.setText(controller.getUserName());

    txtScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtScore);
    txtScore.setTypeface(tf);

    txtValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtValue);
    txtValue.setTypeface(tf);
    txtValue.setText("" + controller.getScore());

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.imgUser:
        onImageClicked(v);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

private void onImageClicked(View view) {
    showPopupMenu(view);
}

private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, view);
    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popupmenu,
            popupMenu.getMenu());
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {



        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item1) {
                //TODO: ...
                return true;
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item2) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Load Image"), LOAD_IMAGE);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }
    });
    popupMenu.show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        imgUser.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }
}

}
```

layout

ImageView has id imgUser, located in RelativLayout user_area_content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/static_area"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/user_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/user_area_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgUser"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="100dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_img_user" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgUser"
                android:text="@string/placeholder"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtScore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtUserName"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgUser"
                android:text="@string/score"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtUserName"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtScore"
                android:text="@string/placeholder"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
        android:name="com.pumperlgsund.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dynamic_frame"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Thx for help!

Comment: Where are you saving the URI of the selected image?

Comment: haven't done that... do you mean that I should save uri and pass it to the imageview in oncreate method. I guess that, when the user deletes the selected picture uri will be null and in that case I should show the default picture, right?
and what do you mean by uri? picturePath or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default image is 'shown again' every time the view are (re)built i.e. every time the `Activity` is created, when the application is started, but also on device rotation. You should save the path to the selected image (in `onActivityResult()`) and retrieve it in `onCreate()`. The simplest way to save the path is probably to use a [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

If you want to restrict the selection to local images, add the [EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY) extra to the intent.

Comment: it works fine. Thx for the help. I also need to check if the chosen picture is deleted otherwise I can get FileNotFoundException, right?